# Commutative diagram with matrices as objects

Tags: diagrams, matrices

I would like to create a diagram which has matrices as objects and arrows between these matrices. In particular, I'd like to have four matrices, two matrices in the upper row, and two in the lower row, with four arrows between them.

I have drawn similar diagram with [`xymatrix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix), but I have no clue how to do this when the objects are themselves matrices.

Help is appreciated.

I tried working in the `\xymatrix` environment, and then use code like this:

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & b^{-1} \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) \]
```

for the matrices, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try?

Comment: Well I basically have no idea what to try... I know how to draw matrices, and how to draw commutative diagrams, but don't know how to put the two together.

Comment: Then show how you would do this. `:)` Then others can combine it for you (and correct anything in your approach if necessary.)

Comment: Well I tried working in the \xymatrix environment, and then put something like this inside: \[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & b^{-1} \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) \]       But this does not work

Comment: Do you realy need the matrices explicitly present in the diagram? Instead of a full matrix, couldn't you just put something like `A` and elsewhere define the matrix `A`? Even if you do try to put in the full matrix, you shouldn't surround it with `\[` and `\]`. Either leave it bare or surround it with `$`s, whichever the xymatrix environment requires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\arrow{r}{\phi}\arrow{d}{\eta} &
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\arrow{d}{\theta} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & c^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\arrow{r}{\psi} &
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & d^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example I used `bmatrix` (from `amsmath`) to build the matrices; if you want to stick to `array`, some extra precautions with the management of the ampersand will be needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & a^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\arrow{r}{\phi}\arrow{d}{\eta} \&
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & b^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\arrow{d}{\theta} \\
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & c^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\arrow{r}{\psi} \&
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & d^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I install the tikz-cd package?

Comment: Your LaTeX distribution should come with a package manager to do the installation automatically for you (`tlmgr` if you use TeX Live, and MiKTeX also has a package manager). Since `tikz-cd` is built upon `pgf/tikz`, you need those installed first and manual installation could be long and difficult.

Comment: You could simplify the code using `\rar` and `\dar` (they are well hidden in the `tikz-cd` manual)

Comment: @daleif yes I know the `\rar`, `\dar`, `\ular`, `\urar` and similar variants, but I prefer to use the long syntax `\arrow{d}{}`, `\arrow{r}{}`....;-)

Answer (score 4):

Btw: matrices works just fine with `\xymatrix` just remember to hide the matrices from the `xy` parser:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix{
    {\begin{pmatrix}
      a & b \\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix}}
  \ar[r] \ar[d]
    & 
    {\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\ c & d
      \end{pmatrix}}
    \ar[d]
    \\
    {\begin{pmatrix}
      a & b \\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix}}
  \ar[r] 
    & 
    {\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\ c & d
      \end{pmatrix}}
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me by a minute. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, thats why the picture is always added via an edit ;-)

Comment: @egreg, btw: do you have ideas for `tikz-cd` such that one can use it inside say `align` without the need for `ampersand replacement`?

Comment: No, `ampersand replacement` is unfortunately necessary, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why? Xy seems to be able to handle it

Comment: PGF/TikZ has a different way of handling `&`.